# app:dexRelease error when generatingsigned apk in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to generate a signed apk but when I build my project i keep getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/AzeezOlusegunOdumosu/android-sdks/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --output /Users/AzeezOlusegunOdumosu/AndroidStudioProjects/RCCGSPP/app/build/intermediates/dex/release --input-list=/Users/AzeezOlusegunOdumosu/AndroidStudioProjects/RCCGSPP/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/release/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/AbstractQueryController$1;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: Find the error message. Google it. Found this. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/issues/26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define

This line means that you have multiple copies of the same library in your dependencies which are clashing.
Probably some parse library which you are using.